# Why are these two substring calls equivalent?

Tags: java, substring

I'm doing a coding question in Java and my solution works but I've seen a different solution someone else posted on their blog that is a bit shorter but I don't understand why it works.

The Question is:

> Given a non-empty string and an int n, return a new string where the char at index n has been removed. The value of n will be a valid index of a char in the original string (i.e. n will be in the range `0..str.length()-1` inclusive).

My code (which works in all conditions):

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
    return str.substring(0,n) + str.substring(n+1,str.length());
}
```

The other code which also works is:

```
public String missingChar(String str, int n) {
    return str.substring(0, n) + str.substring(n + 1);
}
```

The difference is right at the end of the second line.
My question is why does `str.substring(n+1)` produce the same result as `str.substring(n+1,str.length())`?

Comment: Have you actually read the javadoc?

Comment: The `substring` method is overloaded so that you can call it like this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-

Comment: @Jerry Murphy It's not strange, it's the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substring() method has two variants:

`public String substring(int beginIndex)`

or

`public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

The substring begins with the character at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the end of this string or up to `endIndex - 1` if the second argument is given.

Answer (score 0):

When you type:

```
str.substring(n + 1);
```

it means that it will return the whole string from index `n + 1` to the `end of the string`.

And when you type:

```
str.substring(n + 1, str.length());
```

It pretty much means the same thing. It will return the whole string from index
`n + 1` to `str.length - 1`, i.e till the end of the String.

Please read the docs carefully.

[Substring docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))